# Old router as access point

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet, home-networking

Main router: VDSL Zyxel VMG1312-B10A

Access Point router: ADSL Pirelli P.DG A4010G (A-000-1A1-A4)

**My goal/Current state**

Got my main router on the second floor. There are 3 IpTV receivers connected to it with 3 separate Ethernet cables, 2 on the second floor and one on the first floor. Because of the poor wireless signal on the first floor, I decided to use my old router as an access point on the first floor. To avoid connecting another Ethernet cable, my plan was to use the one from the IpTV receiver. Lets move to the problem :)

**Problem**

First what I did was connecting the old router to power and then I connected it to my laptop with the Ethernet cable to set it up. My main routers IP address is `192.168.2.1` and the IP address of my old router is `192.168.1.1`, which I changed to `192.168.1.5`, also, I disable the DHCP. After that I disconnected it from my laptop and connected the Ethernet cable from my IpTV receiver to it. The WiFi was working fine, until I used another Ethernet cable to connect the router with the IpTV receiver. After doing that, the WiFi stopped working and the TV was working fine. I did try with  DHCP enabled but got same result.

Hope someone comes with a solution :D If more info needed please ask.

Thanks!

Edit:

[Main router Zyxel, works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IN3sm.png)

[The Pirelli router after stopping to work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ulp8n.png)

I have set the range from 100 and up for the Pirelli, didint touch the Zyxel one

Comment: Why did you assign it an IP address in a different network? Which router is the one you're trying to use as an access point?

Comment: The Pirelli one. I did assign 192.168.2.2 the first time but same result.
P.S. i wrote the IP addresses wrong it starts with 192. not 168, will fix now

Comment: So, to confirm, you have the Pirelli set to an unused IP address inside your LAN range with its DHCP disabled. The problem is, more or less, that only one device at a time works when connected to the other LAN ports on the Pirelli or the WiFi? When the WiFi stops working, what are the symptoms? Is the network still detected? Can devices connect to it? Can they reach the Pirelli?

Comment: Exactly. After the WiFi stops to work, yes the network is still there and the devices are connected to it but without internet access. As i remember the  Default Gateway was missing.

Comment: If you're going to assign a fixed address, make sure you choose one that's outside the DHCP range. I suspect you have an IP clash with the TV. Also, unless the old router can be set into Access Point mode, do not use its WAN port.

Comment: Yup I did not use the WAN. So you suggest to put an IP like 192.168.2.199?